# wait exit with out all child-process exit

Tags: bash, shell, wait

In my shell script ,'wait' doesn't wait for xx.sh,yy.sh and zz.sh exit! WHY!

```
#main.sh
#!/bin/bash
idx=0
while (($idx<1))
do`cd ff
    ./xx.sh >xx&
    ./yy.sh >yy&
    ./zz.sh >zz&
    cd -
    idx=$(($idx+1))  
done|ls
wait
echo "END"


#xx.sh,yy.sh,zz.sh is for sleep
```

Comment: Your script seems to not even parse..  what's that backtick between `do` and `cd` up to?

Answer (score 2):

the commands are being run in a different subshell, hence the wait doesn't wait for the right processes.  To see this, try

```
./xx.sh >xx &
./yy.sh >yy &
./zz.sh >zz &
wait #this should wait for all of the processes
```

If you want to spawn using a loop, then build the command string to run and then run it in the main script (not within a for loop).

Comment: Sorry,I didn't describe fully.What I need is loop with subshells. But when i add a pipe for read ,'wait' doesn't work!However a redirected input is perfect OK! I can't find WHY!

Comment: Read the answer again. Because the script is not the parent process; the parent process was a subshell which was spawned to run the first step of the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, learned your view. Thank You! I have to learn more about pipeline ( i can't tell who is the parent shell or the subshell).

Comment: @王剑虹 If this helped solve your problem, you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#main.sh
#!/bin/bash
idx=0

( # subshell
   while (($idx<1))
   do
       echo ./xx.sh \>xx&
       echo ./yy.sh \>yy&
       echo ./zz.sh \>zz&
       sleep 5;
       echo "all done";
       idx=$(($idx+1))
    done
)& FOR=$!

echo "Waiting for process $FOR"
wait $FOR
echo "END"
```